# Disable past hour in Material UI DateTimePicker

Tags: reactjs, datetimepicker

Is there any way I can disable selecting the past hour in DateTimePicker https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DateTimePicker
I am using disablePast but seems like it is disabling the past dates but you can select past hour for current date.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: can you share your code sandbox link ?

Answer (score 3):

Ciao, yes you are right, on `DateTimePicker` there is `disablePast` to disable past dates but not past time. Look [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/519), someone asked to add `minTime` prop in `DateTimePicker` to disable past time but there isn't any update on this topic.

The only thing you can do is validate time by yourself like [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/519#issuecomment-609070282) guy have done.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else comes across this and wondering how to resolve this issue, try using,

`disableIgnoringDatePartForTimeValidation={true}`

Not sure when this flag was added, but I am using `"@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.0.4"`