# How to dynamically limit the time range for datetime-local?

Tags: reactjs

How can I set restrictions dynamically on a datetime-local? I wanted to restrict the time where the users cannot select time range between 5pm to 8am?

```
const checkOut = () => {
  const [deliveryDate, setDeliveryDate] = useState();
  
  //convert firebase firestore date to Javascript date
  const date = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(deliveryDate));
  const jsDate = date.toDate();
  const locale = jsDate.toLocaleString();

  //get local time zone and convert to minimum datetime-local
  const localTime = new Date();
  const minDate = moment(localTime).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM");

  return (
    <div>
      <Container fixed>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <TextField
                id="date"
                label="Delivery Date"
                type="datetime-local"
                color="secondary"
                value={deliveryDate}
                onChange={(e) => setDeliveryDate(e.target.value)}
              />
                <Button type="submit">Place an Order</Button>
            </form>
```

Comment: From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#setting_maximum_and_minimum_dates_and_times): *"Depending on what browser you are using, you might find that times outside the specified values might not be selectable in the time picker (e.g. Edge), or invalid (see Validation) but still available (e.g. Chrome)."*. So it allows you to pick time outside range on chrome. See [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/datetime-local-textfield-mui-l2wry). So, try https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datetime-picker instead.

Comment: @AjeetShah will the material-ui datetime-picker be available in all kinds of browsers?

Comment: Yes. To my best of knowledge, it would work in all browsers. You can also have a look at [reactdatepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/), check the section *"Exclude Times"* (that's what you need). But if you are following MUI theme / style, you should go with [material-ui-pickers](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datetime-picker). `TextField` (in your question) is problematic because it depends on HTML5, see [TextField's type prop](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#component-name).

Comment: @AjeetShah I've installed it already, but I'm having an error with "× TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined onChange" I'm using the same onChange from the code above

Comment: I'm not sure. I think it's around here "Uncaught TypeError: _onChange is not a function
    at usePickerState.ts:48" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at onChange (index.js:223)
    at usePickerState.ts:48"

Comment: @AjeetShah i'm using material-ui  datetime-picker

Comment: Everything is working except that I am not able to disable to the Min/Max time: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/datetime-picker-min-max-time-b5inl). It seems like it is [not yet possible to disable the time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63338284/2873538). But you can [disable time with react-datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-exclude-times).

Comment: Or try this workaround: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/519#issuecomment-609070282